# SOAP Web service. Сервис не отображается

Tags: java, spring, soap, веб-служба

Делала веб-сервисы вот по этому [туториалу](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/developing-soap-web-service-using-apache-cxf.html).

Когда делаю копи-паст их классов - все работает нормально, когда же делаю все то же самое, только со своим классом, сервис не находит.

Вот интерфейс:

```
@WebService
public interface AuthorService {
    @WebMethod
    public Author test();
}
```

Это реализация:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "controller.AuthorService",
        serviceName="authorService")
public class AuthorServiceImpl implements AuthorService {
    @Override
    public Author test() {
        return new Author();
    }
}
```

В `spring-context` объявляю сервис:

```
jaxws:endpoint
        id="authorService"
        implementor="controller.AuthorServiceImpl"
        address="/authorService" />
```

Comment: Вам нужно загрузить код куда-нибудь. 
Например, на Гитхаб. 
В двух вариантах: работающий код, неработающий код.
Оба примера должны компилироваться и запускаться.
Тогда кто-нибудь сможет скачать оба примера и посмотреть, в чем разница.